# How did Sauron withstand the seven-year siege of Barad-dûr?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron

We all know that the Siege of Barad-dûr, a key event of the War of the Last Alliance, lasted seven years (S.A. 3434-3441). During that period of time the Last Alliance of Elves and Men kept the bulk of Sauron's forces tied up in the Dark Tower. Even though the Last Alliance of Elves and Men suffered severe losses, at the end, they leveled Sauron's fortress of Barad-dûr and defeated his armies, and the One Ring was cut from his finger and was taken by Isildur.

Is there any Tolkien's reference from scribes about how Sauron and his immeasurable and vast number of Orcs withstood in Barad-dûr those seven years? I mean, are there chronicles of the siege that, from a logistic point of view, recorded how they survived (you know, what they ate, how they restocked their weapons, etc.)?

Comment: ["It looks like meat's back on the menu"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufFOghMt1yI)

Comment: Troy was under siege for a decade. It was periodically supplied by allies within the region because the 'siege' wasn't a total encirclement.

Comment: Do we actually know there was a ‘vast number of orcs’ inside?    Of course Sauron himself withstood it by being a Maia, with no need to eat/drink/sleep.

Comment: Very little is mentioned even about Alliance side of the siege.

Comment: Possssybly Sauorn's armies of orks and men were a lot smaller in number after the Battle of Dagorlad.

Comment: @suchiuomizu - Tolkien told Milton Waldman (letter #131) that, by the time of the siege, Sauron was strong enough to challenge the exiles of Númenor. The exiles comprehended the Númenórean kingdoms of Arnor in the north close to the realm of Gilgalad, and Gondor about the mouths of Anduin further south.

Comment: I don't think Orcs ever formed the majority of Sauron's forces. Eriador, Rhovanion, and Gondor really were just a small part of Middle Earth; they're just the only part we ever see on published maps. To the east and south was a *lot* more land where lived Men that recognized Sauron as their overlord.